# Callback=? significance in AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

The below call failed :

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/MedryBW?client_id=pzaazcrab42neperff77e2elkrqrj4y"
```

This one passed :

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/MedryBW?client_id=pzaazcrab42neperff77e2elkrqrj4y&callback=?"
```

what does this callback=? do ?

Comment: It makes it use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), a way to bypass the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: PROTIP: When posting a question, just saying "failed" doesn't help us help you.  You should show your code and any error messages you see in your console.  You should explain what "failed" means; what you expect the code to do versus what it does do.

Answer (score 2):

The `callback=?` is a "magic" part of the URL that jQuery recognises, and it changes how the request is made.

The callback parameter in the URL is used in a JSONP request, so jQuery change the request from using XHR (XMLHTTPRequest) to using a script element. It also changes `callback=?` in the URL to use a unique function name, something like `callback=callback87624827346`.

As the request is not using XHR, it's not subject to the same origin policy. That's why you can make the request (without setting up [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the server to make the browser allow the request).